# Pushing ViewController works by button, but not with delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, storyboard

The storyboard looks like this
NavigationController -> HomeScreenVC -> LogInVC (modally)
When my logIn is successful I want to dismiss LogInVC and push MyAccountVC
I made a delegate to announce HomeScreenVC when LogInVC is dismissed, but my push does not work
I'll let the code below:

```
func logInSucceded() {
    print("delegate123")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyAccountViewController") as! MyAccountViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}


@IBAction func loginbutton(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyAccountViewController") as! MyAccountViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

I tried to make a direct uibutton(in HomeScreenVC) as a test if I write my push correctly and from the button it works, but logInSucceded() does not.
The print appears in console so I guess the delegate is set up correctly.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is LoginVC dismissed? Do you have an error log like "in window hierarchy" or "already presenting"?

Comment: could you please check if navigationController is present or nil? @Lucaci Norbert-Cristian

Comment: just checked, for some reason the navigation controller is nil in the first one, shouldn't they reference the same navigationcontroller ? @teja_D

Comment: found out I've put delegate = HomeScreenVC() (in LogInVC) and I had a new instance of home screen not the old one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a delegate protocol in your LogInVC

```
protocol LogInDelegate: AnyObject {
    func logInSucceeded()
}
```

In LogInVC, declare a weak delegate property

```
weak var delegate: LogInDelegate?
```

When the login is successful, call the delegate method and dismiss LogInVC

```
func logInSucceeded() {
    delegate?.logInSucceeded()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In HomeScreenVC, conform to the LogInDelegate protocol and implement the delegate method

```
extension HomeScreenVC: LogInDelegate {
    func logInSucceeded() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyAccountViewController") as! MyAccountViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Finally, in HomeScreenVC, when presenting the LogInVC, set HomeScreenVC as the delegate:

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInViewController") as! LogInViewController
    loginVC.delegate = self
    present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

With this approach, when the login is successful in LogInVC, it will call the delegate method, which in turn will dismiss LogInVC and push MyAccountVC from HomeScreenVC.